# Can we interpolate between a logarithm and a constant function with bounded derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, interpolation

I have the following problem. Let $r_0>0$.

Does there exist a family of **smooth** real-valued functions $\phi_{r_0}:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^+$ (parametrized by $r_0$), satisfying

$$
\phi_{r_0}(r) = \begin{cases} \log {r} & \text{if $r \ge r_0$} \\ ? & \text{if } r^*\le r<r_0 \\ \text{const} & \text{if } 0<r\le r^*,
\end{cases}
$$

where $r^*$ is a parameter which depends (in any way you want to) on $r_0$, such that

$$ \lim_{r_0 \to 0}\int_{0}^{r_0} \big(\phi_{r_0}'(r)\cdot r\big)^2 d r =0$$

The constant value $\phi_{r_0}(r)$ takes at $r \le r^*$ may also depend on $r_0$.

The $\phi_{r_0}$ do not need to change continuously with $r_0$. (In fact I will be satisfied with constructing a sequence $\phi_{r(n)}$ which corresponds to $r_0=r(n)$ which tends to zero when $n \to \infty$).

Comment: This can be achieved using convolution with mollifiers. But finding an explicit, closed and simple expression is not that easy (if feasible ?), in my opinion. If it is enough for you I can give details.

Comment: Yes, certainly-that would be great! (I am fine with proof via mollifiers-I don't need a closed-form explicit expression). I would be happy to see the details. Thank you.

Comment: Well using mollifier is possible but actually I have found a quite simple form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\psi$ a $C^\infty$ function whole value is $0$ for $x<0$ and $1$ for $x\ \ge 1$. Such function can be constructed using the standard $C^\infty$ function :

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac 1 x } & \text{ if } x>0 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

And by defining $\psi(x) = \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}$.

Thus the following does what is required, with $C$ some constant :

$$\phi_{r_0}(r) = C\psi\left( \frac {r}{r^*-r_0} - \frac{r_0}{r^*-r_0} \right) + \log r \psi\left( \frac {r}{r_0-r^*} - \frac{r^*}{r_0-r^*} \right).$$

Indeed we only have $C^\infty$ functions involved and I let you verify that the equality on each interval and the condition over the integral are verified for $r^* = r_0/2$ for example.